# Problema com Cors projeto Laravel 5.5 e Vuejs

Tags: laravel, api, cors, axios, jwt

Em um projeto Laravel utilizando os recursos de uma API tenho algumas lógias e tenho meus endpoints no arquivo api.php do Laravel

```
<?php

Route::post("auth", "Auth\AuthController@authenticate");
Route::get("user", "Auth\AuthController@getAuthenticatedUser");
Route::post("refresh-token", "Auth\AuthController@refreshToken");

Route::group(["prefix" => "v1"], function(){
    Route::apiResource('clients', 'Api\v1\ClienteFisicoController');
    Route::get("category/{id}/products", 'Api\v1\CategoryController@productForCategory');
    Route::apiResource('categorys', 'Api\v1\CategoryController');
    Route::apiResource('products', 'Api\v1\ProductController');
    Route::apiResource('states', 'Api\v1\EstadoController');
});
```

foi configurado o pacote de CORS no projeto
[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

então foi seguido a documentação e após isso foi implementado a autenticação utilizando JTW e até ai tudo bem.

o problema se mostra quando eu tento fazer um simples componente para buscar um cep, o detalhe é que esse componente se comporta como esperado quando está em um projeto vuejs sem ligação com Laravel, um projeto apenas de teste.

então tenho o component:

```
<template>
    <div>
       <input type="text" v-model="cep" v-on:keyup="onSubmit">
    </div> 
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
           cep:'' 
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit()
        {
            if(this.cep.length === 8) {
                axios.get('https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+this.cep+'/json/')
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data)
                })
                .catch(error =>{
                    console.log(error)
                })
                .finally(()=>console.log("finally"))
            }
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

esse component lança no log o seguinte quando não há um projeto laravel atrelado a ele.

```
{cep: "77015-012", logradouro: "103 Sul Avenida Juscelino Kubitschek", complemento: "", bairro: "Plano Diretor Sul", localidade: "Palmas", …}
```

e lança o problema de CORS quando está no projeto Laravel.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

por fim em uma tentativa eu criei uma middleware MyCors adicionei ao Kernel.php em middleware, esse arquivo eu coloquei o seguinte em seu contexto.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class MyCors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type, authorization');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse serviço que você está tentando acessar é **externo**, portanto **não** tem como **configurar o CORS** dele **na sua aplicação**.

O que você pode fazer é uma rota no seu backend que acessa esse serviço, por exemplo:

```php
Route::get('address/{cep}', 'Api\v1\AddressController@cepSearch');
```

E somente um exemplo para se ter ideia de como fazer, sem nenhuma tratativa de erro nem nada seria:

```php
namespace Api\v1;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class AddressController
{
    public function cepSearch(Client $client, string $cep) {
        $response = $client->get("https://viacep.com.br/ws/{$cep}/json/");

        return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    }
}
```

E, no seu frontend, você deve chamar essa nova rota criada.

Assim você contorna o problema com CORS.

Comment: Obrigado @Ravan sua resposta está correta.